# maven-exec-plugin throws exception for no apparent reason

Tags: java, windows, exec-maven-plugin

I type the following in a Windows shell in the root of a Maven project that contains a class with a

> public static void main(String[] args)

method that I'd like to run.

> mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.spp.config.main.SqlGeneratorHarness" -e

The class exists and is compiled in that package 
(i.e., target/classes/com/spp/config/main/SqlGeneratorHarness.class).

I see...

```
+ Error stacktraces are turned on.  
[INFO] Scanning for projects...  
[INFO] Searching repository for plugin with prefix: 'exec'.  
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------  
[ERROR] BUILD FAILURE  
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------  
[INFO] Invalid task '.mainClass=com.spp.config.main.SqlGeneratorHarness': you must specify a valid 
       lifecycle phase, or a goal in the format plugin:goal or pluginGroupId:pluginArtifactId:pluginVersion:goal
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Trace org.apache.maven.BuildFailureException: Invalid task' .mainClass=com.spp.config.main.SqlGeneratorHarness': you must specify 
       a valid lifecycle phase, or a goal in the format plugin:goal or pluginGroupId:pluginArtifactId:pluginVersion:goal
       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:1830)
       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.segmentTaskListByAggregationNeeds(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:462)
       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleExecutor.execute(DefaultLifecycleExecutor.java:175)
       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:328)
       at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:138)
       at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:362)
       at org.apache.maven.cli.compat.CompatibleMain.main(CompatibleMain.java:60)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
       at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:315)
       at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:255)
       at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:430)
       at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:375)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: < 1 second
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Sep 27 14:33:52 PDT 2011
[INFO] Final Memory: 3M/122M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I've tried variations like

> mvn exec:exec -Dexec.executable="java" [...]

and

> mvn org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:java [...]

to no avail.  What gives?

I'm running Maven 2.2.1, Java JDK 1.6.0_27 on Windows 7 Enterprise 64-bit.

A snippet from my pom.xml for the exec-maven-plugin is...

```
<plugin> 
   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId> 
   <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
   <version>${exec-maven-plugin.version}</version> 
</plugin>
```

where the version is set in the `<properties>`

Comment: Maven does not found the exec plugin. Show/check your `pom.xml` and `settings.xml`.

Comment: I can see that version 1.2.1 is downloaded into my local .m2 repository. If I manually delete the folder for exec-maven-plugin and retry I get the same exception after it downloads and install the plugin into my local .m2 repo.

Comment: A snippet from my pom.xml for the exec-maven-plugin is...

`<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${exec-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                </plugin>`

where the version is set in the `<properties>` section to be 1.2.1.

Comment: This probably seems insultingly crazy, but... is it at all possible that you've consistently inserted a space or otherwise caused a parsing error directly after `-Dexec` - before the period?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

So... revisiting this... if you use Windows PowerShell, you will get the exception I originally reported.  If, however, you use cmd.exe, then you should be able to run the class with the command as I posted (with or without wrapping double-quotes).

Comment: I wasted a **ridiculous** amount of time trying to run Maven archetype:generate with `-D` arguments with `.` in the arguments from PowerShell. Using `bash` via Cygwin via GitBash it works fine, and `cmd.exe` as well. PowerShell is **THE SUCK!** It is the `.` that PowerShell is trying to parse, once I got a real `bash` shell on my machine, I didn't even try and figure out how to make PowerShell work, ah the warm fuzzies of a shell that works!

Comment: I suspected you might be using PowerShell. I've never used it myself, but I'm not surprised that was the problem.

Comment: This answer is about quotes in powershell http://stackoverflow.com/a/21913401/2822347
So typing (see quotes!) 
`mvn exec:java "-Dexec.mainClass=com.mypackage.Logger"`  may solve the problem

Comment: I meet this problem in powershell,and run the same script in cmd,it ok!

Answer (score 1):

There's something very basic going wrong. Try losing the quotation marks. They're not needed there. In fact, try starting with something simpler, like

```
mvn -e exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=foo
```

That should give you the error "An exception occured while executing the Java class. foo", and the root cause should be a ClassNotFoundException:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: foo
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

Type it out yourself. Don't copy/paste the command from somewhere else.

Comment: I did as you said.  Even without the double-quotes I get the same exception as I posted.  As well, if I type in what you suggested to see if I could get the ClassNotFoundException, I rather received the same Exception as for my own class.  Something is not quite right.  I can issue a `mvn clean install` to build my project and I have no problems.  It must center around config of the maven-exec-plugin. Any other ideas?

Comment: How long have you been using this installation of Maven? Have you ever successfully run `exec:java` with it? If you still have the Maven zip/tar around, check the checksum against those [listed on the download page](http://maven.apache.org/download.html). Perhaps just try downloading and installing Maven again. It seems like it must be a problem either with Maven itself or with the OS's parsing of command line args. Are you using plain old Windows command prompt (`cmd.exe`)? If not, try it from there.

Comment: Oh, you could also try adding a space after the `-D`, like: `...-D exec.mainClass=...`. It's a perfectly legit alternative, and it might shed some light on what's going on.

Comment: Due to time crunch and problems getting exec-maven-plugin to work, I opted for a script.  I use http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/build-classpath-mojo.html to get a string of the effective classpath, then I can just run utility class using java -cp {classpath} com.spp.config.main.SqlGeneratorHarness.

Comment: Ryan, the Maven version I use comes bundled with SpringSource ToolSuite (STS).  It's Maven 2.2.1 and it came bundles with STS 2.7.1.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick checklist:

1. Rename `~/.m2` folder and run `mvn exec:java ...` again and let Maven to download everything again from central.
2. Check that your exec plugin is downloaded from central. (Check that your local repository contains the [same files as the central](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/exec-maven-plugin/1.2.1/).)
3. Looking for suspicious `repository` and `pluginRepository` tags in the `pom.xml` (and parent poms as well).
4. Looking for suspicious `repository`, `pluginRepository` and `mirror` tags in the `settings.xml`.
5. Checking the project in an other machine - copy it and try to build/run exec:java in an other machine.
6. Download Maven 3.x and try to run the exec with it.